# how can I retrieve data from my backend in a table with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to retrieve all usernames from my django backend using axios. The users where shown in a console, but all the details data:(username email...) ,headers, token ....
 So I want to restrict that to just get the data or just show the data in the console 
 After that I want to know how can i put the usernames in a table or a list

This is my retrieve function :

```
 const RetrievUsers=()=>{
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/list') 
      .then(data =>
      console.log(data)
     )

    .catch(err=>console.log(err))

    }
```

The data in my back-end looks like this:

```
"username": "pol",
        "password": "**********************",
        "nom": "a",
        "prenom": "a",
        "email": "a@gmail.com",
        "residence": "po",
        "phone": "po"
```

console :

```
{data: Array(2), status: code, statusText: " ", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, @@@}

/I need only this part 
data:Array(2)
0: email: "a@gmail.com"nom:"a "password: "***pbkd g=" phone: "po"
prenom: "a"residence: "po"username: "pol"__proto__: Object
1: email: "a@gmail.com" nom: "a" password: "*****A4=" phone: "a"
prenom: "a"residence: "pass"username: "a"__proto__: Object
// 
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)headers: { }request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange:   …}status:
```

Comment: This video will explain a lot of what you are asking about. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmL8iaLMnQ0&list=PLillGF-RfqbbRA-CIUxlxkUpbq0IFkX60&index=3

Comment: can you just try consoling data.data like console.log(data.data)

Comment: @akshaykishore thank uuuuuuu it's correct but i can't access the usernames like when i put data.data[0] i get all the data of user 1 and it's a list i think how can i filter this list to get just username

Comment: For putting as table you might be seeking ```console.table()```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for filtering the username just try consoling like this

```
console.log(data.data[0].username);
```

for looping through the data try this

```
data.data.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.username);
});
```